# Rspec / Rails matcher that excepts a model to_be_saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I want to check if the model was persisted to the DB by the various means available. It looks like all these things defer to .save but I'm curious if there is a better way, perhaps using what Dirty provides?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way to check if a new record was created:

```
expect {
  MyModel.do_something_which_should_create_a_record
}.to change(MyModel, :count).by(1)
```

Or, if you're wanting to check that a value was saved, you could do something like:

```
my_model.do_something_which_updates_field
my_model.reload.field.should == "expected value"
```

Or you could use `expect` and `change` again:

```
my_model = MyModel.find(1)
expect {
  my_model.do_something
}.to change { my_model.field }.from("old value").to("expected value")
```

Is that what you were meaning?